# Is there a simple way to monitor when a backup fails twice in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-backup

I am trying to send an SNS notification when a backup in the backup vault fails twice consecutively. Is there a CloudWatch alarm or any other way to do this in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudWatch metrics for this purpose and then setup alarms based on the thresholds that you need.

You can find the list of Metrics that are emitted to CloudWatch in this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/cloudwatch.html

For instance you can setup an alarm on `NumberOfBackupJobsFailed` metric.